# Color-coded top in FreeBSD

Tags: ubuntu, colors, freebsd, top

In Ubuntu (karmic), I can issue top and then press 'Z' or 'B' to color-code or enable bold.

Is there any way (hack or otherwise) to do this in FreeBSD (7.2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the stock FreeBSD top command does not support color.  You may want to check out the sysutils/htop port, as it *does* support color and you can customize it (somewhat).